# iptables port forwarding is not working

Tags: iptables

I have a domestic server, and there are two public IPs on this server:
One is domestic IP: 1.1.1.1
One is the IP of Hong Kong: 2.2.2.2

The default route of the server is to go out from the Hong Kong side of 2.2.2.2. I now have a server 3.3.3.3 in the United States as a scientific server. The port is 2080.

I want to access port 1080 of 1.1.1.1 and redirect the traffic to 3.3.3.3:2080 in the United States through DNAT.

How should it be written?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 1080 -j DNAT --to-destination 3.3.3.3:2080

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This statement has no effect. Server forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Please [append](https://serverfault.com/posts/1127086/edit) a *complete ruleset* as output with, for example, `iptables-save`. For masking public IP addresses you should not invent addresses you don't own like 1.1.1.1. Select specially dedicated addresses from blocks 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24 and 203.0.113.0/24 as descirbed in the [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that the `iptables` rule is actually being applied by running the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -L -n
```

2. Verify that the default route of the server is correct and that the traffic is going out from the Hong Kong side of `2.2.2.2`:

```
ip route
```

3. Verify that server `3.3.3.3` in the United States is able to receive traffic on port `2080`:

```
telnet 3.3.3.3 2080
```

If the connection is successful, the server can receive traffic on port 2080.

4. Verify that any firewalls on server `3.3.3.3` in the United States are not blocking port `2080` traffic.

If those steps didng't resolve the issue, you have to add some logging to your `iptables` rule to see if the traffic is being matched and forwarded as expected:

```
-j LOG --log-prefix "Port Forwarding: "
```

This will add a log message to the kernel log whenever the rule is matched:

```
dmesg
```